# Will TypeScript support the AtScript syntax?

Tags: typescript

I just read a bit about AtScript and how it will be the preferred syntax for Angular 2.0 projects.  I was wondering if there are plans for TypeScript to support the AtScript syntax since they both seem to do the same general thing.

Comment: And what about the other way around? Will we be able to import typescript files as atscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there are plans for TypeScript to support the AtScript syntax since they both seem to do the same general thing.

Nothing publically announced yet. You can track the issue here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/986